# executeUpdate() returns zero despite correct execution

Tags: java, jdbc

### create_PaperBean.java

```java
package Beans;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class create_paperBean extends org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm {

    private String table_name;

    public String getTable_name() {
        return table_name;
    }

    public void setTable_name(String table_name) {
        this.table_name = table_name;
    }
    public String createDB(){
        String str = "creation_failed";
        try{   
            Statement st = DBConnection.DBConnection.DBConnect();
            int insert = st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE "+table_name+"(ques_no int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARy KEY,"
                    + "ques_name varchar(45),ans1 varchar(45),ans2 varchar(45),ans3 varchar(45),"
                    + "ans4 varchar(45),correct_ans varchar(45))");            
            System.out.println(insert);
            if(insert > 0)
                str = "created";            
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(create_paperBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }  
        return str;
    }
}
```

I'm using struts and when this bean is executed a table is created in the database, but the value of insert is still zero! Therefore I can't proceed to the correct page for further functioning of the web app. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`st.executeUpdate()` either returns the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or`0` for SQL statements that return *nothing*.

Creating a table is neither an INSERT nor an UPDATE, so it's normal to receive `0` as no row(s) were affected.

Comment: I don't understand. It successfully creates a new table.

Comment: Yes, it's, but when you insert information to that table later, maybe you insert,update,delete one row, the result will be `1`, or when you insert `n` rows, the result will be `n`, but know you didn't affect anything on the table, you just created table.

Comment: So what can i do to change the string str to "created" after the table is created so that i can move forward.

Comment: `insert == 0` instead `>`

Answer (score 3):

If we take a look at the [Statement.executeUpdate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) javadoc we see that it always return 0 for DDL statements (in your case create table is a DDL statement):

> Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or
>   DELETE statement or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as an
>   SQL DDL statement.
>
> Returns: either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language
>   (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing

You can assume that the statement execution is successful if you don't get a `SQLException`.

Answer (score 0):

I am bit doubted about your query as well, you might need to look at this

```
   CREATE TABLE `test1` ( contact_id INT(10),name VARCHAR(40),
   birthdate DATE,PRIMARY KEY    (contact_id));
```

If the update happens correctly then the value is 1, if not its 0. Moreover, it return 0 when your statement does not affect any row , for example in DDL execution it may return 0.